# loading multiple modules using requireJS in latest firefox 21.0 fails

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I tried with 3 diff modules as defined below

credit.js

```
        define(function(){
            return{
                getCredits: function (){
                    console.log("Inside getCredits");
                    return 10;
                }
              }
        });
```

product.js

```
        define(function(){
          console.log("Inside product");
          return {
            bookTheProduct: function(){
            console.log("Inside bookTheProduct");
            return true;
          }
         }
        });
```

pruchase.js

```
        require.config({
            shim: {
                purchase: {
                    deps : ["credit","product"]
                }
            }
        });
        define(["credit","product"], function(credit,product){
            console.log("purchaseproduct");
            return {
                 purchaseProduct: function (){
                     console.log("Inside of PurchaseProduct");
                     var credits = credit.getCredits();
                     if(credits > 0){
                         product.bookTheProduct();
                         return true;
                     }
                     return false;
                 }
            }
        });
```

used it in app.js

```
        require(["purchase"],function(purchase){
          purchase.purchaseProduct();
        })
```

Tried this in firefox 21.0 ,  while loading purchase it loaded credit module but never loaded product module . If i reverse the order it loads the product module but not the credit module . Didn't find any help in RequireJs documentation nor in mozilla documentation . Also didn't see anyone cribing abt it . did any body ever faced this problem ? I am doing some thing wrong , if so can you please point me the mistake .
    thanks

Comment: Does this code work in other browsers?

Comment: `shim` config option is used to load non-AMD compatible scripts. why do you use it?

Comment: @ricard.m.o. this works well with chrome

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the `shim` configuration is for Javascript files that do not support AMD module definitions and is used to import for example javascript libraries that add some variable to the `window` scope (like jQuery). Read more about `shim` [here](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim).

In your case, all your modules are AMD modules (they are all defined using `define`), so `shim` is not necessary. Instead you can just use the `paths` configuration to create aliases for your modules. Also moving your `require.config` out of the modules and into where your `require` call happens is recommendable.

So, remove the `require.config` from your purchase.js -file, then add the following to the beginning of your app.js -file

```
require.config({
  // with the paths -config, you create aliases for you modules
  // basically you tell require that this file contains definition for module x
  paths: {
    'purchase': 'path/to/purchase', // no .js file ending in the path
    'credit': 'path/to/credit',
    'product': 'path/to/product'
  }
});
```

You can read more about require.config [here](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config).

Now you have configured RequireJS so, that it knows where the modules purchase, credit and product are located and that it will load them. After this they can be referenced with their respective aliases when declaring RequireJS dependencies.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried by removing the shim in require.config, mentioned the path and also moved it to app.js . But still this doesn't work on firefox . I  have tried this on chrome , but that works perfectly fine . Just can't figure out the error.

Comment: Are you using it on the file system or do you have a server running on localhost?

Comment: I am using on file system & i have checked that firefox allows access to local file system . rather chrome doesn't allow it .

Comment: There are no errors? Have you tried putting up some server to see if the problem is related to using the file system?

Comment: I did some more investigation in this matter and found out something interesting .If i run the above code in firefox and put some trace statements ,i get the expected behavior (i.e, all 3 files gets loaded ).But when I'm trying to use firebug for debugging the flow I don't see all the files getting loaded and browser throws error on one of them(credit/product) not defined.Is this happening due to Asynchronous way of loading? Do i have any way to specify the strict order of dependencies,so that execution doesn't start before everything gets loaded(I thought requireJS ensures that).