# require.js dependency loading in Firefox ESR 45.3.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, requirejs

I have a Magento 2 shop (i.e. PHP application) with third party extension, which has complex frontend using hundreds of JavaScript files. Those JavaScript files are require.js modules which look like this

```
define(
    [
        'Extension_Name/js/view/settings/general/element/select',
    ],
    function (Select) {
        "use strict";

        return Select.extend({
            defaults: {
                elementName: 'os_store_credit.show_customer_credit_balance_on_receipt',
                configPath: 'os_store_credit/show_customer_credit_balance_on_receipt'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

I've taken one of the simplest files, some of them are much bigger and with more dependencies. The problem is that in `Firefox ESR 45.3.0` I receive error `TypeError: Select is undefined` in those files. Every page reload causes the first error to happen in a different file. Which to me sounds like require.js starts the code execution before the actual dependency was loaded. I also don't see 404 errors in the Network tab, which means that either dependencies are actually loaded after all or they are never requested.

Problem does not appear in the latest Firefox (49.x) or in latest Chrome (53.0.2785.143).

My question is: how can I approach debugging of that problem?
Is there some sort of debugging/verbose mode of require.js that I can turn on?

I've already been on:
 - [loading multiple modules using requireJS in latest firefox 21.0 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191367/loading-multiple-modules-using-requirejs-in-latest-firefox-21-0-fails)
 - https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/73
 - http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

but none of tips given there seem to apply to my case.

Comment: Did you read the code of `Extension_Name/js/view/settings/general/element/select` and determine that there is no case where it *intentionally* returns an undefined value? The symptoms you describe are consistent with an error in dependencies: sometimes it will work, sometimes not. Unfortunately, there's no verbose mode for RequireJS.

Comment: Hmm, the dependencies' code is usually straightforward, my current assumption is that if there is an error happening inside the dependency code - I should see that error first in the browser console and then see the error which I'm actually getting, but that is not the case somehow.